# switching back to two TableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

All I have two view controllers and they both have a table view on them. Then I have one view controller which displays information. When a user clicks on a row on either table views it segues to the information view controller.

when the user is on the information view controller, I need a back button which goes back to the original one (which can be either one of the two view controllers with a table view on it).

I have considered using segues to go back to the particular table view controller, but when i do that the table view is blank (because I do not want to pass information back to the table view view controller).

I have created this :

```
- (IBAction)whereto:(id)sender
{
    if(self.goback == @"a")
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.goback);
        // go back to RemainderDealViewController
        ReminderDealsViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReminderDealsViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    if (self.goback == @"b")
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.goback);
        // go back to ViewController
```

The Whereto function runs when the back button is pressed and either a or b depends on the original table view controller (the one i want to go back to).

now [self presentViewController doesn't work] and if i use a segue it does work but the tableview is not populated back as it was.

Can anyone advise ?

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationViewController?

Comment: never use segue to go back, if you navigate with presentviewcontroller then go back with dismissviewcontroller, if you navigate with pushviewcontroller then go back with popviewcontroller

Comment: Like @CalinChitu said... also, if you are using a UINavigationViewController you should use "pushViewCOntroller"

Answer (score 0):

For `UINavigationViewController` just use this to present a viewcontroller

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:prod animated:YES];
```

For going back to previous viewController use:

```
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For going to rootViewController use:

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For going to a specific view controller that is in the viewcontroller stack of navigationcontroller use:

```
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

just try this:-

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ReminderDealsViewController *objSec=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReminderDealsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSec animated:YES];
```

Comment: no its doesn't work, it just doesn't move across to the view controller with the tableview. it just doesnt do anything.

Comment: I am using a segue between the tableview and the information page but going back using your code it doesn't do anything but there is no errors either.

Answer (score 0):

to to present a viewcontroller

[self.navigationController pushViewController:prod animated:YES];

to go back you can use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or for root 
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

or for accurate Controller
 //   TO GET  VIEWCONTROLLER

```
NSArray *controller =[self.navigationController  viewControllers];
[self.navigationController  popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```